# Insert text within two brackets - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a typewriter effect so that I start with {} and each letter of the word is typed in every 120 ms. I've almost accomplished this with the following code :

**Javascript**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var index = 0;
var text = 'hello'

// Here you can put in the text you want to make it type.
function type()
{
    document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML += text.charAt(index);
    index += 1;
    var t = setTimeout('type()',120);
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body onload="type()">
...
<div id='screen'>{</div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that while the word is typing, there's no closing brace. So after the first 120 ms it looks like this: {h

But I want it to look like this {h}

How can I fix this?

Comment: Keep a copy of the string that is being shown. start with '{', and the next letter, and assign to `innerHTML`, this copy-string, and a '}'.

Comment: Do you want each letter to be surrounded by braces, or the whole text?  ie: `{h}{e}{l}{l}{o}` or `{hello}`?

Comment: @MikeChamberlain the latter

Comment: I leave you a very nice working example on the my answer http://jsfiddle.net/p56awrea/

Comment: @DiegoLópez yep, just looked at it. thank you. please see my comment to your post.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/p56awrea/2 check it here, the 2 sec delay before looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/p56awrea/2

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var index = 0;
var text = 'hello'
var current = ''

// Here you can put in the text you want to make it type.
function type()
{
document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = '{'+current+'}';
current+=text.charAt(index);
index += 1;

if(index==text.length+1){
    current = '';
    index=0;
    setTimeout('type()',2000);

} else {
 setTimeout('type()',120);
}
}    


</script>
<body onload="type()">
...
<div id='screen'>{}</div>
```

**EDIT**: Added the 2 second delay before looping behavior

Comment: perfect. thank you. As a side note, how would I run this function every time it completes, with like a 2 second pause in between each call?

Comment: Look into `setInterval` for that

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your HTML to the below?

```
<html>
<body onload="type()">
...
<div>&#123;<span id='screen'></span>&#125;</div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I am using the equivalent HTML entities instead of raw curly brace characters.

Edit:
Changed #screen element from a div to a span, which is an inline element

Now you will always have opening and closing curly braces around the text you insert.

Comment: This inserts newlines

Comment: Sorry about that. Will change the div to a span. :-)